# IOS or Android photo editing app to add special effect (e.g. bird or plane) to photos

Tags: android, photography, iphone-app

I currently use Repix (IOS and Android app) to edit photos on my mobile phone, I like repix because it lets me add special effects e.g flying Ravens to my photos.

I'm looking for other apps that I can use to do this, I'm especially looking for one that I can use to add a flying ✈ plane to photos on my phone.

Recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not that deep in photo editing; but I'm pretty sure you want the app do more than just add some ravens. I'd recommend you [edit] your question and list all requirements (see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)), which will significantly increase your chances for good answers. Then, while waiting for those, feel free to check [my list of Android photo editing apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=58) – especially the first two groups should have matching candidates ;)